# Can acids contain OH-?

Tags: acid-base, solutions, ions

Given that a solution contains $\ce{OH-}$ ions can we sufficiently determine the substance is a base? From my understanding, an acid may still contain $\ce{OH-}$ ions. However, the concentration of $\ce{H+}$ ions must exceed this. Is this correct?

Comment: The title is misleading as the term acid has 2 meanings, a substance and  a solution. You obvious mean the latter.

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Answer (score 5):

An acid can have some $\ce{OH-}$ ions, as well as $\ce{H+}$. It is the **relative ratio** that determines if the substance is acid or alkaline. Think of it as mismatching socks, where you must pair 10,000,000 red with 10,000,001 blue socks. There's one blue left over, so blue wins. (Hmm... in that analogy, think red and blue litmus, and there's one more $\ce{OH-}$ ion.)

Also, a [zwitterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwitterion) has both acidic and basic groups, and one can predominate over another, depending on the the pH.

[Amino acids](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/aminoacids/acidbase.html) and [sulfamic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfamic_acid) are two examples. Some amino "acids", such as [arginine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arginine), are more basic, while [aspartic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspartic_acid) is more acidic. [The bumbling biochemist](https://thebumblingbiochemist.com/365-days-of-science/arginine-basic-vs-acidic-amino-acids/) offers a more complete explanation of the behavior of zwitterions.